# Fixing RotMG Socket-Server Security: Error #2048

Tags: networking, realm-of-the-mad-god

[image]

I'd love some really smart networking people to help solve this issue. Every now and again those in my house wanting to play RotMG experience the darned "Socket-Server Security: Error #2048" error. We can log in, but when we try to go to the Nexus the character runs a long time before the error shows up. We never get to the Nexus.

Things we've tried (many of which are suggested as solutions to the problem on different forums):

- Rebooting the router.
- Turning the firewall entirely off on the router.
- Ensuring all computers have accurate time/date.
- Rebooting the computers.
- Using Firefox, Safari, Chrome, and Flash Projector.
- Selecting different servers, both "Best Server" and different specific ones.
- Using multiple different computers.
- Trying to log in repeatedly over multiple hours.

No glory with any of them. The full text of the error message is:

> *Socket-Server Security: Error #2048. Please open port 2050 in your firewall and/or router settings and try again*
>   *Connection failed! Retrying…*

While attempting to connect (and experiencing the error) using the Flash Projector I used `lsof`repeatedly to check out the connections. And guess what? A connection *is* fully established to remote port 2050, repeatedly:

```
phrogz$ lsof -Pnl +M -i4 # results of many runs grepped for the PID

COMMAND   PID     USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
Flash\x20 823      501   15u  IPv4 0xdab61d633f95186b      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.46:50003->172.217.11.244:443 (ESTABLISHED)  
Flash\x20 823      501   18u  IPv4 0xdab61d633f95186b      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.46:50003->172.217.11.244:443 (ESTABLISHED)  
Flash\x20 823      501   27u  IPv4 0xdab61d634050629b      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.46:50056->54.194.34.20:843 (ESTABLISHED)  
Flash\x20 823      501   15u  IPv4 0xdab61d633f94f48b      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.46:50062->54.194.34.20:843 (SYN_SENT)  
Flash\x20 823      501   15u  IPv4 0xdab61d633f94fd83      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.46:50063->54.194.34.20:2050 (ESTABLISHED)  
Flash\x20 823      501   15u  IPv4 0xdab61d634050986b      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.46:50067->54.194.34.20:843 (ESTABLISHED)  
Flash\x20 823      501   15u  IPv4 0xdab61d6339704b93      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.46:50069->54.194.34.20:843 (ESTABLISHED)  
Flash\x20 823      501   15u  IPv4 0xdab61d633f94fd83      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.46:50075->54.194.34.20:2050 (ESTABLISHED)  
Flash\x20 823      501   15u  IPv4 0xdab61d6340584f73      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.46:50077->54.194.34.20:2050 (ESTABLISHED)
```

The last time this happened was on the heels of the Mother's Day server fiasco. After DECA claimed the servers were up, [I experienced this problem](https://www.reddit.com/r/RotMG/comments/6b631t/server_crash_fix_is_live/dhk7mlm/) for a few hours. It magically got better on its own. I mention this to point out that it's not a persistent configuration problem with my home network. With no networking changes we have played the game nightly for hours on multiple computers before and after the error.

This time it's happening after many city-wide power outages. I mention this in case it happens to be an issue with my ISP's configuration after bring up.

Any suggestions on how to further debug—and ultimately solve—this issue?

Comment: This seems less like a game issue, and more of a server issue; if all the browsers are doing the same thing, I don't think it's on the client end of things.

Comment: @Frank I'd agree, except that usually when the servers are acting wonky the [RoTMG subreddit](http://reddit.com/r/RotMG) tends to be full of people complaining. We've been unable to play here for 3 hours but not seen anyone else posting about problems.

Comment: Ugh. Of course, in the last hour of debugging this problem and writing this post, someone _[did post about all servers being down](https://www.reddit.com/r/RotMG/comments/6c19mc/literally_every_server_is_down_at_the_time_of/?ref=share&ref_source=link)_. So…maybe that's the answer. It's just a really poor error message that blames the victim/client for the sins of the servers.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this error message is somewhat generic, where the client is complaining that it cannot connect to the servers. There are various situations where that may be the case. One of them (as described in the error) is when the user's own network has a firewall blocking the port. Another situation that can cause this is when the RotMG servers are tits up and can't be properly reached.

In my case, I happened to be trying to play and debug this when [all the servers were down](https://www.reddit.com/r/RotMG/comments/6c19mc/literally_every_server_is_down_at_the_time_of/?ref=share&ref_source=link). Unfortunately, the error message always blames the client.

You can check the status of the servers at this URL:
http://www.tiffit.net/RealmInfo/api/servers

If you see `true`, it means a server is up and working.
If you see a `false`, it means the server is down.

Comment: Credit to @Frank for prompting me to check the subreddit forum one more time and find the root cause.